# Win Pivot App. Need to access some data from a section. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, function, winjs

I have a JavaScript Win Pivot Application

Into the Hub I am retrieving some information:

```
function initPages(options) {
for (var i = 0; i < options.length ; i++) {
    var menuItem = options[i];
    menuItem.showBanner = (i == 0);

    definePages(options);
}
```

}

and in a .Js file I have the definePages function created:

functions.js:

```
function definePages(item) {
var action = item[0];
var animation = item[1];
var scyfy = item[2];
var localmovies = item[3];
var clasic = item[4];
var comedy = item[5];
var biography = item[6];
var drama = item[7];
var kids = item[8];
var musical = item[9];
var romantic = item[10];
var suspense = item[11];
var horror = item[12];
var art = item[13];
var personalities = item[14];
var history = item[15];
var society = item[16];
```

}

Now, in my section 1 I initialize the page by calling another function there:

```
ready: function (element, options) {
        // TODO: Inicializar la página aquí.
        options = options || {};


        initMovies();
    },

function initMovies() {
    var element = document.getElementById("movieContainer");
    //var movies = ??????????????????????????
    //console.log(movies);
    //it keeps going
}
```

I need to be able to retrive, in that var movies, the var action, from the functions.Js or, which is the same, the items[0]...

However, if I call a function in functions.Js, which is defined in section1Page, it won´t work...

I can call functions and pass data from anywhere to functions.Js, but not the other way around...

Any ideas on what should I do?  Thanks!!!

Comment: "I can call functions and pass data from anywhere to functions.Js, but not the other way around..." 

What appears in the log when you try to call this function? How are you calling it?

Comment: if I call a function from definePages() (that I define in section1Page) the log will say the function is undefined... Ie. definePages(){ takeInfoMovies(action);}   then in section1Page:  function takeInfoMovies(item){var movies = item; console.log(movies);}  *** the program will stop in function definePages saying takeInfoMovies is undefined

Comment: I can say the data I retrieve in the hub is sent from here:                                    function loadMainMenu() {
    var session = WinJS.Application.sessionState;
    var request = new HttpRequest();
    request.service = "utils/menu";

    request.callback = function (data, status) {
        if (isSuccessResponse(data)) {
            WinJS.Navigation.history = {};
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/hub/hub.html", data.responseJSON.Menu);
            return;
        }
        showRestartMessage();
    };
    request.getServerTimeAndPost();
}

Comment: Maybe there is another way to send that data.responseJSON.Menu to the other pages, without Navigation.navigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it... I created a global var in function.Js and I get the info from the array in each section later on:

```
function definePages(item) {
```

tooSleepyToThink = item;
}

section1Page:

```
function initMovies() {
    var elemento = document.getElementById("movieContainer");
    console.log(tooSleepyToThink[0].text);

}
```